# Pick one of union

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to use the type `ImageURISource` which is here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/Libraries/Image/ImageSource.js#L15

```
type ImageURISource = {
  uri?: string,
  bundle?: string,
  method?: string,
  headers?: Object,
  body?: string,
  cache?: 'default' | 'reload' | 'force-cache' | 'only-if-cached',
  width?: number,
  height?: number,
  scale?: number,
};

export type ImageSource = ImageURISource | number | Array<ImageURISource>;
```

However we see that it is exported as a union along with 2 other things. Is it possible to pick from a union just one?

I was hoping to do:

```
$Pick<ImageSource, ImageURISource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very pretty, but  you could use refinement to specifically refine the type that you want out of it by doing something like this:

```
var source: ImageSource = {}
if (typeof source === "number" || Array.isArray(source)) throw new Error();
var uriSource = source;
type ImageURISource = typeof uriSource;
```

The downside here is that if the add more types to the union, your code would start failing again.

It seems like you'd be best off making a PR to react-native to expose that type.

Comment: Yeah that refinement is nasty. I try not to do anything in the js side to refine the type. Just annotations. Ill try that PR. Thanks! Or is it possible to all this refinement in Flow annotations only?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to get a piece of a union, since that would probably be exposing more private details about the implementation than you'd want. You never know if maybe it was aliased with a different name or something anyway.